# Can there be relationship with junction-entity?

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling, erd

On many to many relationship between two entity, there will be a junction entity in between.

My question is, can the junction entity have relationship with another entity? Thank you! (:

Comment: Well, depends on the modeling methodology used. It's only the physical world that needs a junction "table". There are lots of many-to-many relationships which do not have a junction entity. This is why I prefer this notation. http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-pd/pdd0951e/cdug/@Generic__BookTextView/7513;pt=6005

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If the new entity is related to the relationship instead of the two parent entities, then it is definitely possible.

One example :Let's say you want to track the payments made for a particular purchase (of a product) by a customer. You will have the three tables.

```
Customer
----------
Customer_ID,
Customer_Name

Product
-------
Product_id,
Product_name

Purchase (Customer-product-association).
-------------------------------------------
purchase_id,
Customer_ID (FK)
Product_ID (FK)
total_transaction_amt.

Payments (child of purchase)
-------------------------------
Payment_id,
purchase_ID
```

The Payments table above is in a parent-child relationship with the Purchase table (which is a junction entity). Other relationships (such as many-to-many)are equally valid.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it can. Typically a junction entity will be a "weak" entity, meaning basically that it's dependent on another entity. But it's perfectly legal for that weak entity to have a relationship with another entity.

Say, for example, you have a simple auditing system. The audit is made up of sections. Each section is predefined in an separate table. So you have `audit_definition`, which contains the audit definition details, `section_type`, which contains the section template, and `audit_section_definition`, which connects the two so that you know which sections to use for each audit of that type.

Then you have an `audit_instance` table, which contains actual audits of that audit type. To store the section details for that audit instance, you have a `section_instance` table. It's entirely conceivable that you would need a link from `section_instance` to `audit_section_definition`, even though the latter is a junction entity.